# Counting all the keys pressed and what they are (python)

Tags: python, key, counting

I'd like to create a map of the number of presses for every key for a project I'm working on.

I'd like to do this with a Python module. Is it possible to do this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, a possible solution is to install [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and use the [PyCWnd.HookAllKeyStrokes](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyCWnd__HookAllKeyStrokes_meth.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Nick D [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550273/counting-all-the-keys-pressed-and-what-they-are-python/1550298#1550298), on Windows, the [PyHook library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook/1.4/) would work.

On Linux, the [Python X Library](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) gives you access to key-presses on the X-server.

A good example of the use of both libraries is [pykeylogger](http://pykeylogger.wiki.sourceforge.net/). It's open source; see [`pyxhook.py`](http://www.koders.com/python/fidC2A13EA85A1B5C971E93300F93766F58F52A766D.aspx?s=timer) for example for the relevant X library calls.

A lower level option in Linux is to read directly from `/dev/input/*`. The [evdev (ctypes)](http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/python/evdev/evdev.py) and [evdev (c-api)](http://packages.python.org/evdev/) modules may help you here; I don't know much about them though.